# js frontend fetch() post to rails backend filepath to file error

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, rails-api

I'm making a javascript fetch() post request to a rails endpoint. I am using Active Storage to save a picture from my local computer. The browser is not allowing the full file-path through. In a rails front-end with erb I am able to use the picture and view it in a rails view. Going to a JavaScript front-end and posting to the rails API is not as easily done. I know with debugger and binding.pry what is going on in the code. On the js side the file path is obfuscated with fake path. Thus when I hit the rails back-end I get exactly that. I am using the active storage gem and in my model i have a has_one_attached :file

FrontEnd

```
index.html <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">

     //this will hit the endpoint
        fetch(BASE_URL + "/" + "pokemons/test", {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        }).then( response => response.json()
    )
```

BackEnd

```
#=>model.rb 
class Pokemon < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one_attached :file 
#=> backend rails terminal in pry 

    {"nickname"=>"first_try", "species"=>"fictional", "trainer_id"=>1, "file"=>"C:\\fakepath\\WIN_20200205_00_06_57_Pro.jpg", "controller"=>"pokemons", "action"=>"test", "pokemon"=>{"species"=>"fictional", "nickname"=>"first_try", "trainer_id"=>1}} 

terminal_errors: 

ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):

`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a half answer to my problem. It starts with the html and browser attempting to shield my files in my computer and ends with a proper html input form to accept and upload files. [proper form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Now with my html form updated for this specific purpose and even with the proper action to my rails endpoint I can save my image file into Active Storage

here is my html

````
  <div>
    <label for="file">Choose a file</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"> 
    <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname"> 
    <input type="text" id="species" name="species"> 
    <input type="number" id="trainer_id" name="trainer_id">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="test">Send the file</button>
  </div>
</form>``` 

Now that my html is handling the posting action to my rails API I just need a way to open the file and view it.
````